# Need to search for the contacts who's email greeting or Addressee fields have been left blank

Tags: email

When trying to send out mass emails, there are contacts (members) who's email greeting or addressee fields have been left blank in their contact information. Is there a way to search for all these individuals and have them on a list, that way I can go through and add their email greeting? 
Trying to make sure that emails sent out to the public do not start with... "Dear ___," and are more personable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IF you use Search Builder you should be able to build a query like
Contacts + Addressee + Is Null

Ditto for 'email greeting'

Good luck